# Python Web scraper for Stackoverflow

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a newbie Python programmer learning how to design web scrapers. The tutorial I'm following used the code I've posted below and I'm trying to follow it. However, the code runs without displaying any info, plus I get two problem messages in VSCode telling me that:

1. Missing timeout argument for method 'requests.get' can cause your program to hang indefinitely *pylint (missing-timeout) [Ln 4, Col 12]*

2)Missing module docstring *pylint(missing-module-docstring)[Ln 1,Col 1]*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

questions = soup.select(".s-post-summary    js-post-summary")
for question in questions:
    print(question.select_one(".s-link").getText())
```

Comment: `soup.select(".s-post-summary    js-post-summary")` Is there truly a `js-post-summary` element type in `response`? I would doubt as much - have you verified this?

Comment: I inspected the site and saw the div class as such

Comment: Firstly - if that’s a *class name*, you’re missing the `.` in front of it. Secondly - it’s possible the returned content in `response` doesn’t match what you inspected in your browser.

Comment: I have a screenshot to confirm that indeed, that was the class name.
Also, I placed the . in front of the entire _class name_

Comment: I dunno if it helps that the tutorial I'm following is a python tutorial from 4 years ago
The current tutorials I have don't include creating web crawlers

Comment: Right, but in CSS style selectors, *each* class name must be prepended with a full stop.  Additionally, white space between tokens indicates to the parsing engine that it should look for decendants in order of the tokens provided. How about `.s-post-summary.js-post-summary`?

Comment: So if you can kindly help me out with some experimental code, I'd be grateful

Comment: How do I solve the missing timeout arguments problem

Comment: @UltraInstinctShaggy just pass `timeout=5` to your request - make it a really big number if you don't care how long it'll take

Answer (score 0):

You can find each question block using `data-post-type-id` attributes

```
questions = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'data-post-type-id': 1})
for question in questions:
    print(question.find('a', attrs={'class': 's-link'}).get('href')
```

Results will be:

```
questions/74129840/how-to-keep-audio-driver-busy-with-no-sound-output-using-powershell-or-command-p
/questions/74129837/vuejs-how-to-set-value-of-fecolormatrix
/questions/74129835/please-show-me-example-of-software-architecture
/questions/74129833/problem-getting-global-styles-includes-in-storybook-with-nx-and-angular-12
/questions/74129831/not-able-to-figure-out-common-expression-language-conditional-statement
/questions/74129830/why-can-i-successfully-assign-a-ref-to-a-string
....
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to `select` elements with those two classes is:

```py
questions = soup.select('.s-post-summary.js-post-summary')
```

which will select *any* element that has these two classes, or

```py
questions = soup.select('*[class="js-post-summary s-post-summary"]')
```

which will select only elements that have these two classes - but *only* these two classes, and they would have to be arranged in that order as well.

---

**However**, as pointed out in another answer, the questions also have a `data-post-type-id` attribute [`=1`], and that is likely a much better identifier. You can specify that as well with select:

```py
questions = soup.select('*[data-post-type-id="1"]')
```

You can actually even target the `id` attribute by using

```py
questions = soup.select('*[id^="question-summary-"]')
```

to select all elements with `id` that starts with `question-summary-`

---

...and since I've already gone this far, if you just want the question titles, you can just directly use a single select statement:

```py
for qLink in soup.select('*[data-post-type-id="1"] a.s-link'):
    print(qLink.get_text())
```

---

---

And about the two warning messages, I really don't think you need to worry much about them - you can just ignore them; but if they're bothering you, you might want to take a look at [this thread](https://forum.codewithmosh.com/t/hi-im-a-beginner-to-python-as-im-running-my-program-it-works-perfectly-but-i-can-see-a-message-in-problem-saying-that-missing-module-docstring-pylint-missing-module-docstring-can-someone-help-me-to-fix-this-bug/8278) which mentions some ways to either appease or disable the second warning. And for the first warning, you can either disable it similarly or just pass some [timeout](https://datagy.io/python-requests-timeouts/) argument to your request like

```py
response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions", timeout=5)
```

which will raise a `TimeoutError` if the request takes longer than 5sec.